# How to pass data from a alertDialog to ActivityResultLauncher

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am creating an android app with a activity of showing an alertDialog to let user take a photo of a item.

```
// Inside AlertDialog on a Button Onclick function:
Intent camIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
camIntent.putExtra("GET_PRODUCT_ID", product_id);
activityResultLauncherStartCamera.launch(camIntent);
```

On activityResultLauncher, how can i get the "product_id" ?

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityResultLauncherStartCamera = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>(){
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                    Intent data = result.getData();
                    
                    // Both Return a null
                    String product_id = data.getStringExtra("GET_PRODUCT_ID")
                    String product_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("GET_PRODUCT_ID")

                    // Check if old image file exist...
                }
            }
        }
);
```

I need to check if there is a same image file created before and delete it after the user complete to take a new images.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like following reference?

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#custom
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture

```
public class PickRingtone extends ActivityResultContract<Integer, Uri> {
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Intent createIntent(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Integer ringtoneType) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE, ringtoneType.intValue());
        return intent;
    }

    @Override
    public Uri parseResult(int resultCode, @Nullable Intent result) {
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK || result == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return result.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);
    }
}
```